# $E=\{x=(x_n) \in l^2 : |x_k|\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}, \forall k \geq 1\}$ be a subset of $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let
$E=\{x=(x_n) \in l^2 : |x_k|\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}, \forall 
 k \geq 1\}$ be a subset of $l^2$.
I have two questions:

**1. $E$ is bounded ?**  I don't think so, because
$$ |x|^2= \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}|x_n| \leq  \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n} \to \infty, \forall x \in E $$
**Is this right?**

**2. $E$ is compact?**

Comment: Your intuition is correct, $E$ won't be bounded. Hint: there are certain sequences with a finite number of nonzero terms in $E$ which would help you prove that $E$ is not bounded.

Comment: You can replace $k^{-1/2}$ by an arbitrary nonnegative sequence $\{a_k\}\notin \ell^2.$

Comment: I have posted an answer, I hope it helps. Please feel free to accept/upvote and ask any follow-up questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. $E$ is not bounded.

Consider the sequence of sequences $\{\mathbf x^{(n)}\}_{n\ge 1}$ given by $\mathbf x^{(n)} = \{\mathbf x^{(n)}_k\}_{k\ge 1}$
where $$\mathbf x^{(n)} = \left(1, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\ldots, \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},0, 0,0,\ldots\right)$$
Clearly, $\mathbf x^{(n)} \in \ell^2$ for each $n\ge 1$, and $\left|\mathbf x^{(n)}_k\right| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt k}$ for every $k\ge 1, n\ge 1$. Furthermore, we have $$\|\mathbf x^{(n)}\|_2^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|\mathbf x^{(n)}_k\right|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \infty$$
as the harmonic series $\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac 1 k$ diverges. Therefore, the sequence $\{\mathbf x^{(n)}\}_{n\ge 1} \subset E$ is unbounded, showing that the set $E$ is not bounded.

2. Recall that any compact subset of a metric space is bounded. Since $E$ is not bounded, $E$ is not compact either.

---

*Remark:* Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, of which $E\subset X$ is a compact subset. Choose any $x_0\in E$. The balls $\{B(x_0,m)\}_{m=1}^\infty$ constitute an open cover of $E$. By compactness, there exists a finite subcover. In particular, there exists $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $E\subset B(x_0,n)$. By the triangle inequality, we have $d(x,y) < 2n$ for any $x,y\in E$. Thus, $E$ is bounded.